# How to write it differently in php

Tags: php

I need to create a condition where the method block will execute if the number is greater than 78 and less than 86 - I don't know how to do it

```
if($cecha >= 78 AND $cecha <= 86 ){

}
```

How to write it differently in php 7.3

Comment: Well that is how you would do it... With the Less than equals and Greater than equals your If statement will be true for numbers 78 to 86 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "between" but to explain the options...

```
if($cecha >= 78 AND $cecha <= 86 ){

}
```

Will execute for numbers 78 to 86 inclusive, meaning including 78 and 86.

```
if($cecha > 78 AND $cecha < 86 ){

}
```

Will execute for numbers between 78 and 86 not including 78 and 86.

Is that what you are after?

Comment: the problem is that the condition is performed from 0 to 999 not from 78 to 86

Comment: @spamfilter that would seem to be impossible based on the code provided. Are you sure you tested it correctly?